# How do I create a dictionary in f# where value is "generic"

Tags: f#, polymorphism

I am an f# beginner.

I want to create some sort of dictionary where the following applies:

1. The key is a string
2. The value is a generic object of some sort

E.g. consider the following f# script extract that utilizes a c# library where two c# classes (student and teacher) inherit from a common base c# class Person:

```
#r @"D:\Temp\MyCSharpLib.dll"

open MyCSharpLib

let student = Student() // Student inherits from Person
let teacher = Teacher() // Teacher inherits from Person

let eventStream = Map.empty.Add("Key1", student).Add("Key2", teacher)
```

I have attempted to use a Map to do this but I get an error as the compiler expects all values to be of type Student.

Is there any way to do this in f#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in this case F# cannot guess that for the initial map you actually wanted a `Map<string, Person>` and not a `Map<string, Student>`. You can indicate it explicitly:

```
let eventStream = Map.empty<_,Person>.Add("Key1", student).Add("Key2", teacher)
```